# Add a delete entry if exists function to sql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this script to insert a user to another users favourites when the link from their profile is clicked.

At the moment the user can add a user to favourites but i want them to be able to click the button again to remove them from favourites.

So i need to implement a delete if entry exists function somehow and that's where i'm getting stuck. Can someone please show me where i'm going wrong.

Here's my original add user to favourites code:

```
<?php

require_once('includes/session.php');
require_once('includes/functions.php');
require('includes/_config/connection.php');

session_start();

    confirm_logged_in();

    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


}


if (!isset($_GET['to']))
    exit('No user specified.');

$user_id = $_GET['to'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_favorites (user_id, favorite_id) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$user_to_id.")") 
or die(mysql_error());

header($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

?>
```

And here's what i've tried to add to make it delete if the entry already exists:
(This gives me syntax errors and doesn't work)

```
<?php

require_once('includes/session.php');
require_once('includes/functions.php');
require('includes/_config/connection.php');

session_start();

    confirm_logged_in();

    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


}


if (!isset($_GET['to']))
    exit('No user specified.');

$user_id = $_GET['to'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_favorites (user_id, favorite_id) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$user_to_id.")") 
or die(mysql_error());

if ($insert() === true) {
    $delete = (function () use ($connection, $user_to_id) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM ptb_favorites WHERE user_id = ? AND favorite_id = ?";
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

        $result = $statement->execute(array(
            $_SESSION['user_id'],
            $user_to_id
        ));

        return $result;
    });

    $delete();
}

header($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some different ways to do this. I'll start with what might be the quickest (and not very good solution.

### The quick solution

Add a unique index (such as primary key) to **(user_id, favorite_id)** on ptb_favorites (you probably have that already) and then when someone clicks the link you'll try to insert and if you get a duplicate key violation you will delete. It would look something like this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_favorites (user_id, favorite_id) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$user_to_id.")") 
or die(mysql_query("DELETE FROM ptb_favorites WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND favorite_id = ".$user_to_id."));
```

### The better solution

A better and more user friendly solution would be to render the page differently depending on if the user is already a favorite and to create two different links, one for adding and one for deleting. Even if you decide to not change the page you can have two different links. Some pseudo code would look like this

```
if ("select 1 from ptb_favorites where user_id = <my_id> and favorite_id = <page_user_id>") then
  [render delete link and a star in front of user name]
else
  [render add link and just the user name]
end
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, is there a way to use a previous page header on the mysql die? for instance if the user is added to favourites and it runs the insert script it will link back to the previous page like so: function goback()

{

    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

    exit;

}

goback();

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I never code php my self, hence the beautiful pseudo code :)